# jq filter JSON array based on value in list

Tags: list, filter, jq

I want to use `jq` to return the `RuleArn` value if the following condition matches i.e. `.[].Conditions[].Values[]` has an element that matches `app.fantastic.com`

My JSON array:

```
[
    {
        "Conditions": [
            {
                "Field": "http-header",
                "HttpHeaderConfig": {
                    "Values": [
                        "dark"
                    ],
                    "HttpHeaderName": "Environment"
                }
            },
            {
                "Values": [
                    "app.fantastic.com"
                ],
                "Field": "host-header",
                "HostHeaderConfig": {
                    "Values": [
                        "app.fantastic.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "IsDefault": false,
        "Priority": "3",
        "RuleArn": "iwantthisvalue"
    }
]
```

I've tried these:

`| jq -r '.[] | select(.Conditions[].Values[]=="app.fantastic.com")'`

and

`| jq -r '.[] | select(.Conditions[].Values[] | has("app.fantastic.com"))'`

I get the following error:

*jq: error (at :144): Cannot index array with string "Conditions"*

And with this:

`| jq '.[].Conditions[].Values | index ("app.fantastic.com") == 0 | .RuleArn'`

This is the error I get:

*jq: error (at :47): Cannot index boolean with string "RuleArn"*

**Note:** I do not want a solution using `--query` of AWS cli as I use `--query` already to get a smaller JSON payload which I want to filter further using `jq`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of the difficulty you are running into is that the problem statement is improper: `.[].Conditions[].Values[]` does not correspond to your JSON.

Using jq 1.5 or later, you could use the following filter:

```
.[]
| first(select(.Conditions | .. | objects
               | select(has("Values") and 
                        (.Values|index("app.fantastic.com")))))
| .RuleArn
```

Since .Values occurs in several places, it's not clear what the precise requirements are, but you might also wish to consider:

```
.[]
| select(.Conditions[].Values? | index("app.fantastic.com"))
| .RuleArn
```

or (less efficiently, but it works with jq 1.4 or later):

```
.[]
| select(.Conditions[].Values[]? == "app.fantastic.com")
| .RuleArn
```

Comment: Hey thanks Peak, what does this notation mean? `| .. | objects`

Comment: Unfortunately all 3 solutions give me the same error `jq: error (at <stdin>:144): Cannot index array with string "Conditions"`